# Quicksight: Authenticating individual users

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-quicksight

I was going through the amazon quicksight documentation for embedding analytics into my application. Is it really required to have more than one user/reader in your account?
Since most embedded solutions have native web app authentication, can we not authenticate logins to quicksight with just a single reader account and generate the embedding URL and insert it into the iframe in my application?
S
o, we would need only one reader for how many users login to the site. Is this right or am i grossly missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, you wont need more than one quicksight user to serve your users.
We use one account to serve all our users embedded dashboards.
We implement our own authorization layer to determine who can see what.

Broadly speaking, you'll need to federate cognito user pools to quicksight identities.

I'd advise you to have a look at [this step by step tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/embedded-analytics-tutorial-introduction/) (step 6) and this [aws sample repo](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cognito-quicksight-auth) to get a better idea of how it can be done.